# Using equipartition of energy how to calculate the specific heat of aluminium at room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation

Using the concept of equipartition of energy is it possible to calculate the specific heat of aluminium at room temperature ?

For gas molecules it would have been easy as we could use $C_v=\dfrac{R}{\gamma-1}$ or $C_p=\dfrac{\gamma R}{\gamma-1}$. However, as we know aluminium is not a gas at room temperature. So is it possible to calculate it's specific heat at room temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At room temperature you have energy (per atom) of 3kT/2 from kinetic energy of translational degrees of freedom and 3kT/2 from potential energy of vibrations, so you have 3kT per atom. The electron system at room temperature is degenerate and does not provide significant contribution to heat capacity. So you have the Dulong -Petit law. Please see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/Dulong.html#c1 and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/sphtt.html (last column).

Comment: What about rotational degrees of freedom ? And how do you know number of vibrational degrees of freedom is 3 ?

Comment: Also, isn't $\frac{k}{2T}$ energy per degree of freedom only valid for gas molecules ?

Comment: I read the links but it gives very vague explanations..

Comment: @Mystic: Rotational degrees of freedom of one-atom molecules are degenerate ("frozen") at room temperature -this is a quantum effect.

Comment: Do you know any source/link which states the number of different types degrees of freedom for solid atoms ? By the way, thanks a lot =)

Comment: @Mystic: No, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Potential_energy_and_harmonic_oscillators

Comment: @Mystic: Vibrational energy is related to potential energy of atoms in solids: you count the number of normal modes of oscillations, which is roughly equal to the number of translational degrees of freedom.

Comment: @Mystic: Maybe the following will be useful: http://vallance.chem.ox.ac.uk/pdfs/EinsteinDebye.pdf